# Accessing secpol.msc on Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7

How do I get access to **secpol.msc** the **Local Security Policy** Editor from  **Windows 7 Home Premium**.

Do I need to install or enable this for accessing it on **Windows 7 Home Premium**?

Comment: Which edition ? **Its only available in the Professional, Ultimate, and Enterprise editions**

Comment: Possible duplicate..http://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [How do I install gpedit.msc on Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium?](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i) instructions to get *gpedit.msc* installed onto **Windows 7 Home Premium**, and once you have that complete, you can then access the **Security Settings** via *gpedit.msc* to apply the same settings there as the **Local Security Policy** allows via *secpol.msc*.

[image]

Comment: @ClayNichols . . .Could you confirm if one of these answers helped resolve your issue and accept one to close the loop when you ge a chance. I'll be happy to add more detail if needed -- just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The Local Security Policy Editor is only available in Windows 7 Professional, Ultimate and Enterprise Editions only

Reference : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725970(v=ws.11).aspx

Alternatively, you can refer to the [post here](https://superuser.com/a/1018146/270195) and enable **gpedit.msc**